# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE match up to a period (decimal point) or find next sequence in numbers such as Dewey Decimal

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data as such

```
    OC_ID                   PARENT_OC_ID
    4.0.1                   4.0         
    4.0.1.1                 4.0.1  
    4.0.1.1.1               4.0.1.1
    4.0.1.1.2               4.0.1.1
    4.0.1.1.3               4.0.1.1
    4.0.1.2                 4.0.1
    4.0.1.3                 4.0.1
    4.0.1.4                 4.0.1
    4.0.1.5                 4.0.1
    4.0.1.5.1               4.0.1.5
    4.0.1.5.2               4.0.1.5
    4.0.1.5.3               4.0.1.5
    4.0.1.5.4               4.0.1.5
    4.0.2                   4.0
    4.0.2.1                 4.0.2
    4.0.2.2                 4.0.2
    4.0.2.2.1               4.0.2.2
    4.0.12                  4.2 <--------DATA ANOMALLY!!!
```

I am trying to determine the next number in a hierarchy.  For example if I start with PARENT_OC_ID = `4.0`  I need to know that the next available sibling number (OC_ID) within the `4.0.?` hierarchy would be is `4.0.13`

Originally I was using this and this worked.

```
 SELECT MAX(TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (EB_OCS.oc_id, INSTR (EB_OCS.oc_id, '.', -1)+1)))+1  FROM EB_OCS WHERE EB_OCS.parent_oc_id = '4.0'
```

But then somehow the parent to siblings got out of sync and the `WHERE` clause was missing the 4.0.12 sibling and my max number was worng (this is the risk of managing keys manually)

So based on the data anomaly above `4.0` should return `4.0.13` but I get `4.0.3`

I'm taking steps up to the final query and was trying to search using regexp from the starting string and including anything which doesn't have a period (.)

something like this

SELECT EB_OCS.oc_id FROM EB_OCS WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (EB_OCS.oc_id, '4.0.(.*)^.')

but my negative isn't working.

Ultimately I just want the next sequence under a particular level

```
4.0 should give 4.0.13
4 should give 4.1
4.0.1.1 should give 4.0.1.1.4
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `4.0.13` anywhere in your data.  How do you expect it to return that?

Comment: In my original query we find MAX of a bunch of SUBSTRINGs converted to NUMBER and add one.

Comment: Your original solution din't provide a result for `'4'` with the sample data provided - let me know if you need to detect *missing parent on a higher level*; I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column PARENT_OCS_ID is unreliable, simple ignore it and calculate it correct from the child key.
The rest is your original approach

```
 with fix_parent as
 (select OC_ID,
         SUBSTR (EB_OCS.oc_id, 1, INSTR (EB_OCS.oc_id, '.', -1)-1) as PARENT_OC_ID,
         TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (EB_OCS.oc_id, INSTR (EB_OCS.oc_id, '.', -1)+1)) child_number
  from   TST EB_OCS)
 select   
    PARENT_OC_ID,  max(child_number) +1 next_child_number
 from fix_parent
 where PARENT_OC_ID in ('4.0.1.1','4.0','4')
 group by PARENT_OC_ID
 order by PARENT_OC_ID;
```

.

```
 PARENT_OC_ID NEXT_CHILD_NUMBER
 ------------ -----------------
 4.0                         13 
 4.0.1.1                      4
```

To get a result for parent '4' add a line

```
 insert into TST values ('4.0','4');
```

Comment: What is TST? And yes, we need to ignore parent_id column all together.  You are still using it in your query.

Comment: ok I had to remove TST and I see that your parent is an alias

Comment: jeff **TST** ist the name of may TeST table:) replace it with your productive name.

Comment: I think this is working at least in sqlPlus.  I'm integrating into app and will test  there.  I wanted to comment on the `to get result for parent 4 add a line`.  Using all my data 4 does give 4.1.  But it shouldn't matter what the parent id is.  You could have inserted into TST ('4.0', '99999'), right?

Comment: Correct, the parent_ocs_id is not used. You may even consider to drop the column to not give a chance to input wrong values...

Comment: Thanks,my app is working with your query.  I guess I could remove the column and derive the parent when doing my hierarchy query.  If I had used surrogate primary keys then, no I would not be able to delete the parent column because I would loose the relationship b/n parent sibling.   The query that you helped with is for when inserting a new sibling under a parent.  I would have to modify my query to find siblings under parent.  In my sample data above 4.0.12 is really under parent 4.2 and not parent 4.0.  I would have to fix this anomaly so record with oc_id 4.0.12 has oc_id 4.2.something.